# Adding floating point precision to qnorm/pnorm?

Tags: r, floating-point, precision, normal-distribution

I would be interested to increase the floating point limit for when calculating `qnorm`/`pnorm` from their current level, for example:

```
x <- pnorm(10) # 1
qnorm(x) # Inf
qnorm(.9999999999999999444) # The highst limit I've found that still return a <<Inf number
```

Is that (under a reasonable amount of time) possible to do?  If so, how?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the argument is way in the upper tail, you should be able to get better precision by calculating 1-p. Like this:

```
> x = pnorm(10, lower.tail=F)
> qnorm(x, lower.tail=F)
10
```

I would expect (though I don't know for sure) that the pnorm() function is referring to a C or Fortran routine that is stuck on whatever floating point size the hardware supports. Probably better to rearrange your problem so the precision isn't needed.

Then, if you're dealing with really really big z-values, you can use log.p=T:

```
> qnorm(pnorm(100, low=F, log=T), low=F, log=T)
100
```

Sorry this isn't exactly what you're looking for. But I think it will be more scalable -- pnorm hits 1 so rapidly at high z-values (it is e^(-x^2), after all) that even if you add more bits they will run out fast.

Comment: Even though this answer is more than 8 years old, the lower.tail=F solution was just what I needed. It reminded me of ["Mata Matters: Precision"](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/1536867X0600600407?icid=int.sj-abstract.similar-articles.2) by William Gould which provides an explanation as to why 1 - pnorm can cause precision issues. "It is addition and subtraction which are the real killers." pg. 557.