# How can I get rateratio() to return more p-value digits?

Tags: r, p-value

Using `fmsb` to calculate incidence rate ratios.

Example:

```
rr <- rateratio(853, 7703, 284, 3508)
rr
Cases   Person-time
Exposed    853     284
Unexposed 7703    3508
Total       8556    3792
```

Incidence rate ratio estimate and its significance probability

```
data: 853 7703 284 3508
p-value <2.2e-16
95 percent confidence interval:<br/>
1.274426 1.468068
sample estimates:
[1] 1.367824
```

Then when I try to return the values to store later in a table:

```
p <- rr$p.value
p
[1] 0
```

How can I change the format so that it returns the p-value with more digits? Preferably 3 or 4 or in scientific notation.

Answer (score 2):

`fmsb::rateratio()` does an imprecise computation of the tail value of the Normal distribution, resulting in the value underflowing to zero.  You can fix this yourself (it would be public-spirited to contact the maintainer (`maintainer("fmsb")`) to suggest this improvement to the package).

Save the source code of the function to a file:

```
dump("rateratio",file="my_rateratio.R")
```

Edit the file in a text editor (or RStudio or whatever) and change line 14, which is

```
p.v <- 2 * (1 - pnorm(abs(.CHI)))
```

to

```
p.v <- 2 * pnorm(abs(.CHI), lower=FALSE)
```

(which is an equivalent, but more accurate computation: see `?pnorm` or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932276/adding-floating-point-precision-to-qnorm-pnorm-in-r)). Then read the file back in:

```
source("my_rateratio.R")
```

(this creates a new version of `rateratio()` in your global workspace, masking the version from `fmsb`).

Now if you re-run the code you'll see that `rr$p.value` is `2.893638e-18`.